# How to add content to pages using a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, php

I am developing a plugin for Craft 3. And I am trying to add some content to all pages in the CMS using this plugin. How can I do that? Is there a method or class call I can use for this? I am not sure where this is mentioned in the docs either.

Basically I want to add a few lines of HTML, CSS and JS in all the pages of the CMS if my plugin is installed and enabled in that Craft installation. Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: Could you explain your use case for this? There could be a more suitable solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your plugin you can check for a front-end request, and if so inject an [asset bundle](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/asset-bundles.html)

```
public function init()
{
    // Check if front end request

    $request = Craft::$app->getRequest();
    if (
        $this->isInstalled
        && !$request->isCpRequest
        && !$request->isConsoleRequest
     ) {
        $this->registerAssetBundles();
    }
}

protected function registerAssetBundles()
{
    // Include CSS on front end
    $view = Craft::$app->getView();
    $view->registerAssetBundle('vendor\\plugin-handle\\assetbundles\\YourpluginFrontendAssets');
}
```

I'm not sure it's possible to inject html, I believe you would need to write a [new variable](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/extending-twig.html#extend-the-global-craft-variable) to render your html.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you kind sir. :)
Small question, if I had to add attributes to my js and css files, how to do that in the asset bundle?

Comment: $jsOptions Figured it out :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to place a hook tag in all templates then you could [register a new template hook method](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/template-hooks.html#app) in your plugin.

Twig:

```
{% hook 'my-custom-hook-name' %}
```

Your plugin:

```php
Craft::$app->view->hook('my-custom-hook-name', function(array &$context) {
    $context['foo'] = 'bar';
    return '<p>Hey!</p>';
});
```

For injecting CSS or JS you would use

```php
\Craft::$app->getView()->registerCssFile("file.css");
\Craft::$app->getView()->registerJsFile("file.js");
```

If you can't modify the template files to place a hook tag there you could dynamically generate the markup in your JS file, depending on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to listen for the [before render event](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-web-view.html#event-before-render-page-template) on the view class.